# How to compare many to many fields in a Django model?

Tags: python, django

Given the following model example, how could I compare the two M2M fields when querying the model?

```
class PaidModel(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile)
    paid_users = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile)
```

I am trying to find which 'PaidModel' instances have 'users' that do not match 'paid_users' (i.e. are assigned but not paid for). I tried F objects as follows:

```
unpaid = PaidModel.objects.exclude(users=F('paid_users'))
```

This returns a queryset but the two M2M fields didn't match as expected. I was trying to avoid iterating through and 'manually' finding the non-matching instances.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why two M2M models, not single M2M field with `through` option with additional `paid=true/false` field? Currently you can have `paid_users` records without corresponding `users` row.

Comment: Hi @IvanStarostin. The user can have multiple purchases so I don't think a single boolean field would work would it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand neither how is this related to my comment, nor to your model. Fine, user can have multiple purchases. Why two m2m fields? which one of them means what?

Comment: I thought you where saying that I should include a boolean on the through model (UserProfile) which I thought would limit the user to a single 'purchase'. Could you provide more details on your initial comment please? Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Apologies for the slow up take!